# Execute else statement only if looped through the array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 arrays `currentLocation and allLocation`

```
currentLocation =[
    {
      "name":"AAA",
      "locationCode":"room"
    }
    ];

    allLocation=[
    {
      "name":"SSS",
      "locationCode":"Hall"
    },
    {
      "name":"PPP",
      "locationCode":"Building"
    },
    {
      "name":"SSS",
      "locationCode":"room"
    }
];
```

I am checking each `currentLocation` data with all `allLocation` data.If it matches it returns `alert("Inside Location")` otherwise it should return `alert("Out of location")`.

Here is code:

```
currentLocation.forEach(function(eq){               

        var valid=false;
        allLocation.forEach(function(d){
          if(d.locationCode==eq.locationCode){
            alert("Inside location")
            valid=true;
          }
        })
        if(!valid){         
            alert('Out of location')
        }

    })
```

My query is `if(!valid)` should execute once `currentLocation` data is compared with all `allLocation` data.But its executing for each `allLocation` data.what I did wrong here?

Comment: d.id is not d.locationCode??

Comment: @Saeed.At sorry check now.

Comment: I copy paste the code in browser console, it runs well! :S

Comment: Your code works well. https://jsfiddle.net/SmitRaval/xpvt214o/86190/

Comment: the use of `.forEach` here is not justified. A better approach is to use a [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop where you can break the loop if you got your match.

Comment: ok I will check my actual code.Thanks guys for your precious time:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
currentLocation =[
{
    "name":"AAA",
    "locationCode":"room"
}
];

allLocation=[
{
    "name":"SSS",
    "locationCode":"Hall"
},
{
    "name":"PPP",
    "locationCode":"Building"
},
{
    "name":"SSS",
    "locationCode":"room"
}
];

var valid = false;
currentLocation.forEach(function(eq){ 
    allLocation.forEach(function(d){
        if(d.locationCode==eq.locationCode){
            alert ("Inside location")    
            valid=true;
        }
    }) 
}) 

if(!valid){         
    alert ('Out of location')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to show alert as many as the all location size?

```
allLocation.forEach(function(al) {
    currentLocation.forEach(function(cl){
        if(cl.locationCode == al.locationCode){
            alert ("Inside location")
        } else {
            alert ("Out of location")
        } 
    }) 
})
```